# How can Zend_Db be used to update multiple tables using joins?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

Is there an equivalent to the following SQL using the Zend_Db modules?

```
UPDATE items,month SET items.price=month.price
WHERE items.id=month.id;
```

The [mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) states

> ... multiple-table UPDATE statements can use any type of join permitted in
>   SELECT statements, such as LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 3):

You can always execute a query string.

```
$db->query("UPDATE items,month SET items.price=month.price WHERE items.id=month.id")
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 1):

With MySQL, you can use `JOIN` (left, right or inner) in `UPDATE` the same way as you would in a `SELECT` statement.

Your code would look like this:

```
$sql = <<<END
    UPDATE table1
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.other_id
    SET table1.newvalue = 'value'
    WHERE table1.id = 99
        AND table2.other_value = 'value'
END;

$result = $db->query($sql);
```

The `$result` variable will contain an object related to your adapter type.  I use PDO_MYSQL so I ended up with a `Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo` object.